# reactjs firebase authentication update profile does not refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

In my reactJS app, I am using firebase authentication. I can login successfully. I tried to update user profile, like photoUrl and displayName as follows. Data is updated but I can't get the latest update data unless refresh the page.

Please ignore `updateCurrentUser` function. it is an API call to update display name and photo URL to database.

after `updateCurrentUser` function callback, I call again

```
const auth = getAuth();
const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
```

But updated display name and photo is still old data in `currentUser`. I want to know how can I update profile. I am showing the user info in the header section as well.

#### updateUser function

```
async function updateUser(updateUserId, displayName, photoUrl) {
const auth = getAuth();
const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
return await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: displayName,
  photoUrl: photoUrl,
})
  .then(async function () {
    const auth = getAuth();
    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      updateCurrentUser(updateUserId, displayName, photoUrl)
        .then((updatedUser) => {
          if (updatedUser) {
            const auth = getAuth();
            const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
            setUser(currentUser);
            setAccessToken(currentUser.getIdToken(true));
            store.dispatch(saveUser(currentUser));
          } else {
            setUser(null);
            setAccessToken(null);
            store.dispatch(saveUser(null));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw error;
        });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    throw error;
  });
}
```

Comment: what about the console is it up with the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase show updates of user profile only after refresh and automatically after login/logout operation. The only way you can do this will be by using the same values you submitted

```
async function updateUser(updateUserId, displayName, photoUrl) {
const auth = getAuth();
const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
return await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
  displayName: displayName,
  photoUrl: photoUrl,
})
  .then(async function () {
    const auth = getAuth();
    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      updateCurrentUser(updateUserId, displayName, photoUrl)
        .then((updatedUser) => {
          if (updatedUser) {
            const auth = getAuth();
            let currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;
            currentUser.displayName = displayName;
            currentUser.photoUrl = photoUrl
            setUser(currentUser);
            setAccessToken(currentUser.getIdToken(true));
            store.dispatch(saveUser(currentUser));
          } else {
            setUser(null);
            setAccessToken(null);
            store.dispatch(saveUser(null));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw error;
        });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    throw error;
  });
}
```

Comment: I add this line  await currentUser.reload(); above setUser(currentUser); currentUser is refresh. But still photo on header navigation bar does not refresh until refresh the page or click the other route. So now the problem is that profile component does not re-render after value in context is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I make a silly mistake. It is wrong spelling. It should be photoURL instead of photoUrl. It is working when refresh because, at api server side, need to update user info again. At server side, variable name is correct.